# Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement newrelic-plugin-agent

Tags: pip, newrelic-platform

I tried to install MeetMe `newrelic-plugin-agent` as described in https://github.com/MeetMe/newrelic-plugin-agent with PIP

but, I have this error message :

```
#pip install newrelic-plugin-agent

Downloading/unpacking newrelic-plugin-agent
  Real name of requirement newrelic-plugin-agent is newrelic_plugin_agent
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement newrelic-plugin-agent
No distributions at all found for newrelic-plugin-agent
```

The logs are :

```
------------------------------------------------------------
/usr/local/bin/pip run on Sun Jun 23 12:21:48 2013
Downloading/unpacking newrelic-plugin-agent

  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/newrelic-plugin-agent/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/newrelic-plugin-agent/: HTTP Error 404: Not Found (newrelic_plugin_agent does not have any     releases)
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/newrelic-plugin-agent/ when looking for download links for newrelic-plugin-agent
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Real name of requirement newrelic-plugin-agent is newrelic_plugin_agent

  URLs to search for versions for newrelic-plugin-agent:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/newrelic_plugin_agent/
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/newrelic_plugin_agent/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/newrelic_plugin_agent/: HTTP Error 404: Not Found (newrelic_plugin_agent does not have any     releases)
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/newrelic_plugin_agent/ when looking for download links for newrelic-plugin-agent
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement newrelic-plugin-agent
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After installing the Plugin Agent today on Ubuntu 12.04, I enhanced the guide that MeetMe provides.
Try the following steps:

1. Install pip:

   `$ sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev build-essential`

   `$ sudo pip install --upgrade pip`

   `$ sudo pip install --upgrade virtualenv`
2. For certain plugins there might be additional installations, so check out the plugin instructions.
   [MongoDB plugin for example needs python driver for Mongo]
3. Copy the configuration file example to /etc/newrelic/newrelic_plugin_agent.cfg and edit the configuration in that file to enable the plugin and set the New Relic license key:

   `$ sudo cp /opt/newrelic_plugin_agent/etc/newrelic/newrelic_plugin_agent.cfg  /etc/newrelic/newrelic_plugin_agent.cfg`
4. Change ownership of newrelic folders to newrelic user:

   `$ sudo chown newrelic:newrelic /var/run/newrelic`

   `$ sudo chown newrelic:newrelic /var/log/newrelic`
5. Run the agent:

   `$ sudo newrelic_plugin_agent -c /etc/newrelic/newrelic_plugin_agent.cfg`
6. If the process is not staying up try to run it as foreground process and check out the output:

   `$ sudo newrelic_plugin_agent -c /etc/newrelic/newrelic_plugin_agent.cfg -f`

Comment: you're right. The problem is that PIP wasn't up to date. Thanks !

Comment: python seems pathetic in that none of the versions are compatible with each other and projects never mention what version they work with...

Comment: Just something to update, the package name for 1.3.0 has now been changed to newrelic-plugin-agent, instead of newrelic_plugin_agent