# Not able to download pyxplorer package using pip?

Tags: python

I referring url to profile data and to profile the data we need pyxplorer inside of python interpreter but when i try to install pyxplorer package it gives me error like:

Collecting pyxplorer
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyxplorer (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for pyxplorer

command to install package is:

pip install pyxplorer

I know below link only about data profiling(pyxplorer)

1) https://github.com/grundprinzip/pyxplorer
2) http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/grundprinzip/pyxplorer/blob/master/pyxplorer_stuff.ipynb

The links which I have already tried are:

1)[pip cannot install anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17416938/pip-cannot-install-anything)

2) [Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement newrelic-plugin-agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17260730/could-not-find-any-downloads-that-satisfy-the-requirement-newrelic-plugin-agent)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The same thing happens to me on Ubuntu 16.04. Have you satisfied all the dependencies here?: https://github.com/grundprinzip/pyxplorer#dependencies

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the `pyxplorer` package on PyPI is invalid and doesn't actually contain any release data. Have a look at the releases key of the [JSON for `pyxplorer`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyxplorer/json) - it's an empty array, but normal packages look more like [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy/json).

The best solution would be to install directly from GitHub, like so:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/grundprinzip/pyxplorer
```

(You may need to use `sudo` on Unix-like systems or *Run as Administrator* on Windows)

It might also be wise to file an issue on the `pyxplorer` bug tracker so they know about this.